# makecluster in R opens parallel sockets but does not use them all

Tags: r, sockets, parallel-processing

I'm using foreach package in R. I do `cl<-makeCluster(no_cores,outfile='log.txt')`
`registerDoParallel(cl)`to open the sockets, and I use 10 cores because I have 10 independent calculations to run in my loop. I can see that the sockets are opened, I get from htop:

> 32315 elise     20   0  205M 32404  3612 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.18 ├─ /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore -e parallel:::.slaveRSOCK() --args MAST
>
> 32301 elise     20   0 1154M  964M  4168 R 100.  0.7  0:08.16 ├─ /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore -e parallel:::.slaveRSOCK() --args MAST
>
> 32289 elise     20   0 2793M 2591M  4332 S  0.0  2.0  0:36.99 ├─ /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore -e parallel:::.slaveRSOCK() --args MAST
>
> ...

for each of the 10 sockets.
My problem is that during the calculation only one or 2 of the cores are used, instead of the 10, even if the 10 calculations are independent.
My R code:

```
output=foreach (i=1:nb_sets,
       .combine=list,
       .multicombine=TRUE,
       .export=c(...),
       .packages = c("e1071","ROCR")) %dopar% {...}
```

and nb_sets=10.
What is even more weird is that this code used to work fine before (run calculations pretty quickly on the 10 cores), so I think there might be an issue on the server side, but I have no idea what it could be.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be causing the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So after meeting this problem several times I think I have an answer:

1. The reason why going parallel was slow is because, I think, the memory was getting overloaded (because of the different jobs that were running at the same time). Indeed, rparallel does not have a safe mode to trigger `gc()` if the memory is overloaded.
2. However, looking at htop I could not see the memory getting overloaded (which is weird).
3. The server might have had less available working memory than before.

**Solution:** I splitted the data.